# iOS App Extension Widget not updating with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, widgetkit

I have a simple app that uses CoreData defined as follows:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ListObject> = ListObject.fetchRequest()
        
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
   managedObjectContext: self.viewContext,
   sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
   cacheName: nil)

fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
var objects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppModel")
           
let storeURL = URL.storeURL(for: "group.company.group", databaseName: "AppModel")
let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]

container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in

  self.viewContext = container.viewContext
  self.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
  self.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
  self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
}

// Save

  viewContext.perform {
    if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
       try self.viewContext.save()
          WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
     }
  }

// Widget
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {

  let simpleEntry = createEntry(index:0)
  let entries = [simpleEntry]
  let nextUpdateDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())!
  let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextUpdateDate))
}
```

However when I call 'save()' in the app, then dismiss the app, the corresponding CoreData update is not available in the widget (rather the old data still persists, almost as if its being cached).

I have tried DarwinNotifications, ensuring 'Background fetch/processing' is enabled, called reloadAllTimelines, tried to ensure all saves/reads are on the same thread (viewContext.perform) - however nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to force a widget to update with the latest data from CoreData?